# JQuery Autocomplete - Different color text based on value

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to look through the jquery-ui.js file at the autocomplete function. I have autocomplete working just as I would like, however I would like to add a feature. I would like the color of the results to change for that single line item based on the value.

For example if the text value contains the substring test, the color of the text should be red instead of what is defined using the css color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I had to edit this part of the code in the auto complete section of the file. I added a check that looked at the item.label value, if the value called for a color change I added the red style to the anchor tag (style="color:red;").

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
        .append( $( "<a>" ).text( item.label ) )
        .appendTo( ul );
},
```